# Putting put string text in javascript raise syntax error

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel 8 / blade/ jQuery 3.5.1 app I need to put string text in javascript like :

```
L.marker([{{$adLocation->lat}}, {{ $adLocation->lng }}]).addTo(locationMap)
 .bindPopup("<b>Add Location!</b><br />"+'{!! crlf($adLocation->content) !!}'+".").openPopup();
```

I try to replace crlf characters with method like

```
    function crlf(string $s) : string
    {
        return str_replace( array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $s);
        
        // 2 lines below does not work too
//        return preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $s);
//        return  nl2br($s);
    }
```

But anyway I got error :

```
edit:539 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

and I see in browser : https://prnt.sc/wtpnri and https://prnt.sc/wtq78t

Which way is valid ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is very disordered, and your elaboration on the question is a bit ambiguous. Please try to explain your question a little bit clearer.

Comment: I ordered my post. Hoe it is clear now. I want to get valid text under .bindPopup( method.